# Pause ExoPlayer from Adapter class when user navigates away from page playing the video

Tags: java, android

In my Adapter class I have implemented code for the `ExoPlayer` and it works fine. The question I have is, when the user navigates away from the page with the videos, I want the `ExoPlayer` to stop automatically. Can't figure out a way to do that.

If they are on the same page but just scroll down for example, the video shouldn't stop, but if they navigate away from the page playing the video, the video should pause or stop.

And it's my Adapter class, so I can't call `onPause()` and `onResume()`, or is that wrong?

In my other Activity I used `onPause()` and it works fine, but here I have to do it differently, right?

Do I manually have to go through and write code to pause the video with each click that navigates the user away from the screen with the videos?

```
 public void setVideo(String videoUrl) {

            try {
                BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter.Builder(mContext).build();
                TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter));
                mExoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(mContext, trackSelector);
                Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(videoUrl);
                DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("posts");
                ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();
                MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(videoUri, dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);
                mPlayerView.setPlayer(mExoPlayer);
                mExoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource);
                mExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(false);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("ViewHolder", "ExoPlayer error: " + e.toString());
            }
        }
```

**In my EditVideoPostActivity I did it like this which works**

```
@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(false);
        mExoPlayer.getPlaybackState();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use a different Exoplayer instance in your adapter class, use the Exoplayer from your activity, and handle the life cycle there as you have done. To play videos after an item is clicked, you should use to call back to your activity and play the video from there. In that case, since your Exoplayer is tied to your activity life cycle when the user navigates from the page, the player would stop.

Comment: I don't have a different Instance of the ExoPlayer in my Adapter class. I created the ExoPlayer in the Adapter class, not in the Fragment, and I need to pause it by onPause(); or something similar when the user navigates away from the page, or the ExoPlayer is no longer occupying the view. Can you tell me how to achieve that?